# R Wont See My Variables

Tags: r

I am loading a straightforward csv file into R:

```
college=read.csv("College.csv",header=T)
```

I have the rows named in the far left, headers in the columns, and numbers for data.

It looks like this when I do a fix(college):

```
row.names    applicants    accepted
 college1       800          600              ...
 college2       344          211
 ....
```

When I do a:

```
summary(college)
```

I get the expected results.

When I do a:

```
summary(applicants)
```

I get the following error:

```
error in summary(applicants):  object 'applicants' not found.
```

I am a beginner.  Is there a setting I need to check on my set up?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you did not create a variable called `applicants`.
Do :

```
applicants<-college$applicants
summary(applicants)
```

If college is a dataframe you can also do : `attach(college)` and the names of your `dataframe` will be attached in the environement (meaning that you can use `summary(applicants)` directly as the variable `applicants` will exist. That way all of your other columns will also "exist", you will then avoid to have to call them `college$nameOfVar`.

If college isn't a dataframe you can do : `college<-as.data.frame(college)` to transform it. If you don't know if it is a dataframe do `str(college)` or `class(college)`and it will tell you what kind of object it is. But given that you used `read.csv`it should already be a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you!  Attach was what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
summary(college$applicants)
```

College is the data frame, applicants is a variable in the data frame. You need to tell R where it can find applicants, by adding the data frame in front of it with the $ sign in between.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that for all columns in my dataframe. I have (50+ columns) named but calling that name doesn't do anything unless I do what you did.

Comment: Just run `summary(mydataframe)` and it should give you a summary of all seperate columns.

Comment: Categorical data summary shouldn't be meaningful right? Only columns whose values are integer or double would be insightful from the print out rihgt?